# R I'd like to count the number of patients by var "evnt" via group_by or nrow

Tags: r, group-by

I have a dataframe with the format

```
  Id_patient Evnt_chr
1         30     evnt
2         30     evnt
3         30 Not evnt
4          1 Not evnt
5          1 Not evnt
6          9     evnt
7         89     evnt
8         89 Not evnt
```

I need to get data frame in the following form:

```
Evnt_chr     Nb_id_patient  %
evnt         3              75
Not_evnt     1              25
```

Thank you for your help

Mathieu

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post pictures of data because we cannot copy/paste the values for testing. Use a `dput()` or something more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Id_patient) %>% 
  summarize(evnt = if(any(Evnt_chr == "evnt")) "evnt" else "Not evnt") %>%
  `[[`("evnt") %>%
  table() %>%
  cbind( 100 * ./sum(.)) %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("Nb_id_patient", "%"))

#>          Nb_id_patient  %
#> evnt                 3 75
#> Not evnt             1 25
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't properly present my problem.
I want to count the total number of patients who have had at least one "Evnt_chr".